# Unable to create docker machine with Digital Ocean

Tags: docker, digital-ocean

On my DigitalOcean account I have created a Droplet. On the command line, I then enter

```
docker-machine create --driver digitalocean --digitalocean-access-token=[my_access_token] test
```

(without the brackets).

But the result I get back is

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(test) Creating SSH key...
(test) Creating Digital Ocean droplet...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: POST https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets: 422 You specified an invalid image for Droplet creation.
```

I'm just in the very beginning of the process of creating a docker container. All I'm trying to do is pass my DigitalOcean access token to docker-machine, and I've already encountered an error, so I'm not sure what could be causing it.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/digital-ocean/), and have done a lot of googling, but haven't found any similar problems. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The end of that error message should give you a hint what went wrong:

```
You specified an invalid image for Droplet creation.
```

Specifically, you specified *no* image.  In order to create a droplet on DigitalOcean, you always need to specify at least an image (e.g., `ubuntu-14-04-x64`), a size (e.g., `2gb`), a region (e.g., `nyc2`), and a name (You used "`test`").

Rerun the command with the `--digitalocean-image` etc. options specifying your desired values.

Comment: but according to the instructions that I linked, that doesn't seem necessary. I also don't have any images. I'm creating everything from the very beginning.

Comment: @AlanH: I now notice the "The DigitalOcean driver will use `ubuntu-15-10-x64` as the default image." line in the docs.  That was a poor choice by the driver author, as 15.10 is a non-LTS and now EOL release that DigitalOcean no longer provides!  All DO customers have access to about 60 public images, which are the same options displayed when creating a droplet in the web interface.  The closest equivalent to `ubuntu-15-10-x64` now available is `ubuntu-16-04-x64`.

Comment: I would have never figured that out. Thanks!